# What is time machine backing up?

Tags: software, time-machine

Is there a way to find out what time machine is backing up?

My time machine has been running fine, but it suddenly started to back-up 20GB a few days ago when I have not changed that much since last back-up.

This morning it started to back-up 14Mb, but I have not used it since it's last back up at 00.01 am.

Thanks,

Linda

Comment: Some of these answers are reported as not working on Lion - you might look here as well - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15717/how-to-see-what-files-were-changed-in-timemachine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TimeTracker](http://www.charlessoft.com/) is a quick-and-dirty application that displays the contents of your Time Machine backups, and shows what's changed since the previous backup.

Comment: I'd suggest BackupLoupe over TimeTracker; it's a bit more polished and probably would be less buggy

Answer (score 9):

There are two tools I know of that do this: (1) [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) (which is a GUI application) and (2) [timedog](http://code.google.com/p/timedog/) (command-line Perl script).

Comment: BackupLoupe is stellar in presenting the changes so you can see which are taking the largest incremental space. It is visually stunning as well. +1 indeed

Comment: BackupLoup is now located at http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/

Answer (score 7):

## Mobile Time Machine and Time Machine in Lion: using Terminal to view activities

### At any time

A command such as this will present a lightweight overview:

`tail -f /private/var/log/system.log | grep -E 'backup|mtm'`

### During a backup

A command such as this will present detail:

`sudo fs_usage cmd backupd`

### When you have finished

To interrupt a running command:

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

### tmutil

From the manual page for `tmutil` in Mac OS X 10.7 (Build 11A511), the description:

> tmutil provides methods of controlling and interacting with Time Machine, as well as examining and manipulating Time Machine backups. Common abilities include restoring data from backups, editing exclusions, and comparing backups.

Expect Apple to publish that manual page, and others for 10.7, at:

- API Reference: [Mac OS X Manual Pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/)

Comment: I've tried that in El Capitan but I mostly see entries like `01:48:38    THROTTLED    0.024550   backupd` and no actual paths.

Comment: `sudo fs_usage cmd backupd` saved the day for me. Apparently postgres has been failing to start every 10 seconds since 2013, and time machine can no longer handle the number of files in that directory.