# How to see what files were changed in TimeMachine?

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

I tried TimeTracker, tms and timedog but none of them works with OS X 10.6

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Lion has come out with the `tmutil` command and the man page shows that it will crawl a specific backup and report very detailed information on your specific backups. The verbs **compare**, **uniquesize**, and **calculatedrift** look most useful if you don't mind the terminal.

I still use [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) on Lion (as well as on older OS) and have high praise and thanks to the team that built it every time I need to use it. I should probably send them more money, too. It's that good.

[image]

It makes it very easy to see what files are taking the most space between backups and also is indispensable for knowing when a specific file has been changed by tracking each time it is saved as a new version going back in time. It works on a local database so you are not crawling the filesystem each and every query - just once each time to collect the deltas for each backup.
[image]

Comment: BackupLoupe - great tip.  Solved my problem, too many caches and extra app specific backups inside ~/Libary/Application Support.

Answer (score 6):

Since Time Machine uses hardlinks to store unmodified files (and directories), this would mean that changed files in the latest backup will have a link count of 1 since they are unique. Use this together with find to generate a listing:

```
find /path/to/your/latest/backup -type f -links 1 -print
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It just displays all files.

Comment: Actually - this does work for me. I tested several folders with more than 2000 photos, and each time it picked out the 20 or 200 ( or zero) files that were new that backup. I still like http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/ but this seems to answer the question as to what's new in a backup with a clever and speedy find command.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built in `tmutil` and GNU `gsort`:

```
brew install coreutils
```

To compare between two specific backups:

```
cd "/Volumes/TimeMachine/Backups.backupdb/My Mac"
sudo tmutil compare Date1 Date2 | gsort -h -k2
```

For just the difference between the current backup and the previous backup:

```
sudo tmutil listbackups | tail -n 2 | awk '{ print "\""$0"\""}' | xargs tmutil compare | gsort -h -k2
```

Comment: Note that using APFS, the path to the backups is now something like `/Volumes/.timemachine/[UUID]/2023-04-26-170302.backup/2023-04-26-170302.backup/`, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436157/198134

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that find command seems to be that HFS allows hard links on directories as well as regular files.  As a result, files that have not been backed up for a while will show up with one link but one of their parent directories may have many links.